# use of if/else statement with pexpect

Tags: pexpect

I am trying to write a script in which I would like to access the switch with tacacs credentials with the help of interactive pexpect module. However I would like to use if/else statement and accordingly send different command.

For example:

1) Expecting '**password:**' and sending login password.

```
abc:PythonScripts$ ssh username@ip_address
password:
```

2) Expecting "**Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?**" and sending command '**yes**'.

```
abc:PythonScripts$ ssh username@ip_address
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Answer (score 0):

hey have you solve this?
I'm on the same situation and I'm trying to evaluate the returning value of the c.expect('connecting')
and using that on if statement but I'm not sure because also I'm trying to put all the commands into a function to just call it instead to write it many times

Edit:

I found this

```
index = p.expect (['good', 'bad', pexpect.EOF, pexpect.TIMEOUT])
if index == 0:
    do_something()
elif index == 1:
    do_something_else()
elif index == 2:
    do_some_other_thing()
elif index == 3:
    do_something_completely_different()

instead of code like this:

try:
    index = p.expect (['good', 'bad'])
    if index == 0:
        do_something()
    elif index == 1:
        do_something_else()
except EOF:
    do_some_other_thing()
except TIMEOUT:
    do_something_completely_different()
```

src: [http://www.bx.psu.edu/~nate/pexpect/pexpect.html](http://www.bx.psu.edu/%7Enate/pexpect/pexpect.html)

Comment: You found that. Does it help? Does it solve the question at the top of this page? If yes please delete everything which does not match [answer] and explain how the shown code solves the problem. Currently your post risks being misunderstood as a question with some code you have doubts about and hence should be deleted by you. (good style however, linking to where you found)